# CORS and non 200 statusCode

Tags: nginx, cors, http-status-codes

I have CORS working well with Nginx. The APIs are designed to send non `HTTP 200` status code, for example, `401`, `404`, etc., in case of bad input. The problem is that Chrome cancels/abort the request if it receives a non `HTTP 200` status code. Due to this reason, I am not able to show the exact error on the Web client.

What is the way around for CORS non 200 status code errors?

Answer (score 17):

By default Nginx only adds headers for requests it considers successful. You can make it add the header without regard for the response code, by adding the `always` parameter to your `add_header` directive, e.g.

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
```

Adding the `always` parameter to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not enough. The `always` parameter needs to be added to the headers that need to be always added. In some cases, you will need to add the `always` parameter to the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
```

Comment: It gives error: `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "add_header" directive in /etc/nginx/include.d/cors:37`

Comment: This is probably too late, but which version of nginx are you using? The `always` keyword was added in v1.7.5.  
For earlier versions you will have to use `more_set_headers` as mentioned bellow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the more_set_headers module.

with -s you can scpecify more status code

`more_set_headers -s '404,400,403' 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain.com';`

However if you don't have installed this module in nginx you need to recompile it.
to compile it :

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.7.8.tar.gz
git clone https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module.git
tar -xzvf nginx-1.7.8.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.7.8
./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --add-module=/path/to/headers-more-nginx-module
make
make install
```